# How to programmatically retrieve the name of default audio input device on Windows XP?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, audio, windows-xp

How to programmatically retrieve the name of default audio input device on Windows XP (eg: "Realtek AC97 Audio")?

I can access it through the registry key "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Multimedia\Sound Mapper", but I'm not sure if this is always reliable. Also, I can retrieve the names of all devices by using waveInGetDevCaps() api, but I'm not sure how to get the default audio device name using it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAL to the rescue! Since OpenAL lets you query that type of information, how to do it must be hidden in the source code.

Digging through it reveals [this code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=de#Wag-gKnV1r8/Alc/winmm.c&package%3aopenal&d=1&l=104) which leads to [waveInGetDevCaps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd743841%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

The `WAVEINCAPS` structure holds, among other data, the name of the device.

Comment: Hi Damon, I can get the details of all devices using waveInGetDevCaps() (as mentioned in my question) but how to determine which among all the returned devices is the default input device ? BTW, thats a good link! I'm digging through it to see if it answers my specific question.

Comment: [This](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=de#Wag-gKnV1r8/Alc/ALc.c&q=alcCaptureDefaultDeviceSpecifier&l=1554) looks like they just use the first one.

Comment: Another solution may be to use [IMMDeviceEnumerator::GetDefaultAudioEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as in [this sample](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthew_van_eerde/archive/2008/06/13/sample-find-out-if-your-default-playback-and-capture-devices-are-on-the-same-hardware.aspx). That should give you _explicitly_ the device that the system believes is the default one (Vista only, though, no XP).

Comment: Looks like using the first device from the list returned by waveInGetDevCaps() will be enough as windows will make sure the device_id = 0 is always assigned to default audio endpoint (both input, output) on XP and below.

Answer (score 2):

Try using WAVE_MAPPER:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void CALLBACK waveInProc(HWAVEIN hwi, UINT uMsg, DWORD dwInstance, DWORD dwParam1, DWORD dwParam2) {
    printf("Device opened for recording!\n");
}

int main(void) {
    HWAVEIN hwi;
    WAVEFORMATEX wfx;
    WAVEINCAPS wic;
    int sampleRate = 44100;

    wfx.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    wfx.nChannels = 2;
    wfx.nSamplesPerSec = sampleRate;
    wfx.nAvgBytesPerSec = sampleRate * 2;
    wfx.wBitsPerSample = 16;
    wfx.nBlockAlign = wfx.nChannels * wfx.wBitsPerSample / 8;
    wfx.cbSize = 0;

    //Get capabilities using WAVE_MAPPER (ID for Microsoft default assigned device)
    waveInOpen(&hwi, WAVE_MAPPER, &wfx, (DWORD) &waveInProc, 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION);
    waveInGetDevCaps(WAVE_MAPPER, &wic, sizeof(wic));

    //Use the received manufacturer id to get the device's real name
    waveInGetDevCaps(wic.wMid, &wic, sizeof(wic));
    printf("%s\n", wic.szPname);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Hi Midas, I tried the example but unfortunately it still seems to return the details of Sound Mapper (the dummy device that is represented by WAVE_MAPPER id) instead of the real one. Also the documentation seem to suggest that the first parameter of waveInGetDevCaps() is device_id instead of manufacturer's id :(.

Comment: How does it still display the details of Sound Mapper? Try the code in a new program, it should work.